# Timeout not working in my android mobile app

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

Good morning, I'm using Axios in a mobile application, however I found that the timeout specified before the request is not working in my application, but only on the Android side, in IOS it works normally.

{ "baseURL": "https://api", "method": "GET", "timeout": 1000 * 20, "url": "/url/conexao", }

What I noticed on Android is that: if I configure a very small timeout, for example 10ms, axios respects that and returns me 'timeout of 10ms exceeded' and even then the request is not performed, in case the timeout is greater and the request is waiting for a return, the timeout is not triggered.

Axios Version
1.4.0

Adapter Version
Http e Https

Node.js Version
18.3.0

OS
Android S - 12.0 x86_64 e IOS 16.4

Additional Library Versions
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuRii.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11yuq.png)